# Responsive HTML in Email

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, gmail

I am trying to create a HTML Template which I will use to send emails. 
In template, I have a single row table which I want to make it either completely horizontal or completely vertical like below depending on screen width.

**in laptop or desktop it should look like this**
[image: in laptop or desktop]

**and in mobile devices it should look like this**

[image: in mobile devices]

```
 <style type="text/css">

body {margin: 0; padding: 0; min-width: 100%!important;}

.content {width: 100%; max-width: 600px;}  

.subhead {font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; letter-spacing: 10px;}

.h1 {font-size: 33px; line-height: 38px; font-weight: bold;}

.h1, .h2, .bodycopy {color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;}

.button {text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 30px 0 30px;}
    .button a {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;}
    </style>


    <table>
        <tr>
      <td class="innerpadding borderbottom">
        <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
         <table width="40" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
          <tr>
            <td height="40" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use css media quires ..

Comment: @saina media queries are not allowed in most of the email clients.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bootstrap? It would make your life very easier. And would involve less code.

Comment: could you please paste a link here ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/. It's a framework so the downside is you'll have to sit down and learn it. It is however very easy to learn (won't take you more than 5 hours if you really focus on it - and you'll probably know how to do what your asking in your question in a less than an hour)...

Comment: mail clients does not supports external CSS that is why I can't use bootstrap here. Please refer to this link
[link] http://help.verticalresponse.com/how-to/tutorial/the_dos_and_donts_of_email_html/ [/link]

Answer (score 0):

sample :

```css
 table { width: 90%; }
 td { height: 40px; padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px; border: 1px solid #333; }  
 @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  td { display: block; width: 90%; }
 }
```

```html
<html>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/mail_2.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: most of the email client removes media queries. Is there any alternate solution ?

Comment: Yes that is sad but true. it removes javascript too.